# Antlr4 typescript target, ErrorNode is undefined

Tags: typescript, antlr4

I am trying to write a funtion that checks if a node has a ErrorNode as one of its (in)direct children. But ErrorNode shows up as undefined.

```
function hasErrorNode(node: ParserRuleContext) {
    console.log(ErrorNode) // undefined
    if (node instanceof ErrorNode) { // Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
        return true
    }
    for (const child of node.children!) {
        if (hasErrorNode(child as ParserRuleContext)) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I checked for cyclic dependencies, i do not have any (i verified it with the tool [madge](https://github.com/pahen/madge))

I expect to be able to check if a node is an instance of an ErrorNode instead i get an error `right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object` presumably because its undefined.

if relevant, this is how I import `ErrorNode`

```
import { CommonTokenStream, ParserRuleContext, TerminalNode, ErrorNode, Interval, CharStream } from 'antlr4';
```

*And this code gets compiled with webpack into cjs*

Answer (score 1):

The correct import is from the /tree folder:

```
import { ParseTree, ErrorNode, TerminalNode } from "antlr4ts/tree";
```

Comment: I am not using antlr4ts, do i need to?

Comment: I tried `import {ErrorNode} from 'antlr4/src/antlr4/tree'` but that showed up still as undefined

Comment: Oh, you used that new "TS runtime" from ANTLR 4.12? Well, that's incomplete. No wonder you cannot find certain types. For the import from antlr4ts use the import as I have given it, not via the src folder (which is not exported).

Comment: Yeah i did, thanks anyway! From the [TS target](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/typescript-target.md) i figured it was just the JS target with declaration files. No that it wasnt finished. Would this then considered a bug? Or expected since it is incomplete?

Comment: I would consider it a bug, yes. From what I know there's some work going on to improve this runtime, but I don't follow it closely, as I'm working on my own [TS target](https://github.com/mike-lischke/a4tstool/tree/master/runtime/org/antlr/v4/runtime).